# Image is not posted in Tumblr

Tags: android, tumblr

I used the code, which is mentioned in the link https://github.com/FredrikL/android-ttTumblr. When i use this code, it was successfully logged in after that i'm trying to post a image or text or quote or video nothing will be posted. I can't understand why it will happening. Any one can explain why it will not post. One of my application need Tumblr. In my application i must post image and text. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you attempting to make a post? Please, show us some code so we have something to go off of.

Comment: @Ally: The above code works fine. Initially i done click ViewDashbord option it goes to their site. Instead of that goto menu the click account. in that i enter my account credentials then post Image, message and Quotes it works fine.

Comment: i click on menu button,then select account enter credentials and on click save i got error email and/or password is incorrect. any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have post image and text with Tumblr Example Downloaded from github.

Check [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867481/how-to-post-image-or-text-in-tumblr-android/25073702#25073702) for more details.

And, It works!