# How to Post image or Text in Tumblr Android

Tags: android, tumblr

```
    I am Working on Tumblr integration in Android but not able to login
```

Downloded the SDK from following Url:-

```
http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/android-sdk
```

now i need to login and post image or text in Tumblr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Tumblr Example](https://github.com/RobertSzkutak/AndroidExamples)

Set `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` and Get Started!

About posting text and photos see [Tumblr API #Posting](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting)

> Text Post

API Url : `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blogname.tumblr.com/post`

Replace blogname with your BlogName.

Params : 1) type = "text" 2) title = "MyTitle" 3) body = "My Message"

> Photo Post with text

API Url : `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blogname.tumblr.com/post`

Params : 1) type = "photo" 2) caption = "Text with Image" 
3) source = "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"

If any doubt's, feel free to ask.
Hope this will help you out.